# What sounds more natural and clear - "to set free potential" or "to release potential"?

Tags: word-usage, translation

I tried to translate a phrase but found it difficult to choose proper words. What version of my phrase looks (sounds) better?

1. A leader is a person who has set free his potential of a leader
2. A leader is the one who released his leader potential
3. (some mixture of the above two)

Thank you,

Comment: ...who has set free his potential _as_ a leader. But putting "leader" at the beginning and end of the sentence  sounds clunky.

Comment: "... who has set his potential free..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working backwards from the noun, you could use any of the following:

- leadership potential
- potential to lead
- potential to be a leader

Then, for the verb, either *achieved*, *attained* or *realised* would work with any of the above.

But even then, the phrase sounds rather redundant. If someone told me that *"A leader is a person who has achieved their leadership potential"*, I'd have no complaints about the grammar but I'd feel like they're stating the obvious.

Comment: What if I avoid redundancy saying this way, "The one, who has release their leadership potential, is now a leader"?

Comment: @PavelEhlakov, The new suggestion seems to retain the original redundancy, but this issue is secondary. I agree with the sense of the answer given, in that *potential* does not generally follow the metaphor of being released, as something already inside, but as being moved toward from a different place. Thus, *to achieve one's potential*, or *to realize* it are much clearer choices. Concerning the question of making a statement that not redundant, perhaps you would like to describe what you think a leader is, as in, *A person with leadership potential is ---, ---, and ---*.

Comment: Another attempt. Imagine a worker is given a tool. But he's never used it. A tool is potential. If a peson is given that potential but never exposed it, or used it, nobody can say he has the tool (potential). Shall I better say, "A learer is the one who used (applied) the leadership potential given to them"?